# how can I access @-values of preceding-sibling in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to determine the distance between two trackpoints  in the 9th line of my xsl file by calculating it using the longitude and latitude of the current and previous trackpoint .

```
<xsl:value-of select="6378.388 * math:acos(math:sin(@lat) * 
math:sin(preceding-sibling::@lat) + math:cos(preceding-sibling::@lat)
 * math:cos(preceding-sibling::@lon-@lon))"/>
```

Processing it using Saxon9 it just says there is an unexpected token "@" after axis name. (line 9 math:sin(**preceding-sibling::@lat**))

I am quite not sure how to access the given @-value of the preceding or following node because it works exactly like this on the current node.

Help or Tips are appreciated.

I will provide you with my GPX and complete XSL file

My GPX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
 <trk>
  <name>ACTIVE LOG140135</name>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="48.750527" lon="10.001063">
    <ele>632.169</ele>
    <time>2008-08-09T13:01:31Z</time>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="48.750499" lon="10.001105">
    <ele>629.469</ele>
    <time>2008-08-09T13:02:05Z</time>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="48.750539" lon="10.000982">
    <ele>634.398</ele>
    <time>2008-08-09T13:03:07Z</time>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="48.750561" lon="10.000870">
    <ele>643.272</ele>
    <time>2008-08-09T13:18:38Z</time>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="48.750560" lon="10.000927">
    <ele>641.713</ele>
    <time>2008-08-09T13:18:50Z</time>
   </trkpt>
...
```

And here my xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="trkseg">
    <xsl:for-each select="trkpt">
    <xsl:value-of select="6378.388 * math:acos(math:sin(@lat) * math:sin(preceding-sibling::@lat) + math:cos(preceding-sibling::@lat) * math:cos(preceding-sibling::@lon-@lon))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you want is this...

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lat
```

Note the use of the `[1]` to get only the first preceding sibling. Without this, the expression `preceding-sibling::*` will get all preceding siblings (and so all attributes of those siblings), which would cause `math:sin` to fail with the error "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of math:sin()"

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error is gone. Now I will just have to figure out why the shown value always is NaN.

Comment: Perhaps because you apply it to the first trackpoint, where preceding-sibling selects nothing?

Comment: I solved the NaN-Error today. It was just a problem with the operations in the formula.